# Как в React правильно подключать CSS из node_modules?

Tags: reactjs

Изучаю React. Наблюдаю такую ситуацию в разных примерах кода. Есть например Bootstrap или Purecss, которые добавляются к проекту через NPM. Способ подключения таких CSS в React-приложениии разный. Где-то используют react-css-modules, а где-то указывают просто путь до нужного файла в директории node_modules.

1) Как в итоге правильно подключать css из модулей?

2) Стоит ли вообще подключать CSS в React-приложении, если используется webpack? Наверное можно как-то сконфигурировать для сборки нужных css и подключения их в index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, не никакого "правильно". Если какой-то метод работает для вас и работает хорошо, значит так оно правильно, правильно?

Чисто теоретически, лучше стараться убирать глобальные зависимости, то есть не подключать css через html файл. html файл, кстати, тоже можно генерировать вебпаком.

Поэтому я бы остановился на одном из следующих вариантов

1) `import 'path-to-bootstrap.css';`

2) entry-запись в конфиге вебпака

В обоих случаях, нужно в вебпаке добавить в разделе module->rules лоадер style-loader и css-loader и желательно прописать include: "node_modules", чтобы потом можно было разбить css бандл на два - ваш и vendor (всё что заимствовано).

Плагин ExtractTextPlugin позволить выщать css в отдельный css бандл (по умолчанию всё пойдёт в js бандл)

HtmlWebpackPlugin генерирует html файл

HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin копирует файлы и папки при билде

CompressionPlugin сжимает в gzip

Если не получается сконфигурировать вебпак - пишите

Comment: А если говорить о том, как писать собственные стили (раз вы заговорили про react-css-modules), советую перепрыгнуть через все этапы развития компонентной идеи человеческа применительно к стилям и сразу переходить к styled-components.